# SQL search script from CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me with this.

```
SELECT
   Username,
   CASE
      WHEN UserType = 'DUMMY' AND UserLoginId = Username THEN 'Awaiting_Approval'
      WHEN UserType = 'DUMMY' AND UserLoginId != Username THEN 'Checking_Approval'
      ELSE 'No_Status_Yet'
   END AS UserStatus
FROM MyTable
WHERE UserStatus LIKE '%king%'
```

I try to create simple search by text from database, so I can search by middle of the text. Because of there is no status column in there, I create it myself from combination of 2 column details. Can anyone help me. Thanks.

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement. (Returns a value.)

Comment: Your logic makes no sense to me.  What is the purpose of the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: Without WHERE clause, these data shown up in the table list. So, when user type some text insert the search field, I need to search it. That's why I need to add WHERE clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a alias directly in WHERE clause, try the below one

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  Username,
           CASE
              WHEN UserType = 'DUMMY' AND UserLoginId = Username THEN 'Awaiting_Approval'
              WHEN UserType = 'DUMMY' AND UserLoginId != Username THEN 'Checking_Approval'
              ELSE 'No_Status_Yet'
           END AS UserStatus
    FROM MyTable
)   AS  D
WHERE UserStatus LIKE '%king%'
```

Comment: True, but this query makes no sense.

Comment: ya, may be. I think this is not a complete query , may be a sample part of query to show the scenario by OP.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could add your case expression on the `WHERE` clause.

Like

```
SELECT
   Username,
   'Checking_Approval' AS UserStatus
FROM MyTable
WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN UserType = 'DUMMY' AND UserLoginId != Username THEN 1
          --other conditions that should be returned here
            ELSE 0
          END
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use HAVING keyword (works only in MySQL):

```
SELECT
    Username,
    CASE
        WHEN UserType = 'DUMMY' AND UserLoginId = Username THEN 'Awaiting_Approval'
        WHEN UserType = 'DUMMY' AND UserLoginId != Username THEN 'Checking_Approval'
        ELSE 'No_Status_Yet'
        END AS UserStatus
FROM MyTable
HAVING UserStatus LIKE '%king%'
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but this trick might only work in MySQL (not SQL Server).